# Install F# 4.5 to Docker Container

Tags: docker, f#, .net-4.8

I require the use of F# 4.5 running on the .NET Framework (not .NET Core). I would like this environment running in a docker container as it'll run periodically on our Jenkins build server. I thought that I could use the existing [.NET Framework SDK Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk) but it only has F# for .NET Core/.NET 5.

So I attempted to install F# into the running container (should that work, I would add it to the image itself) but I am not having any luck. Here was my attempt...

1. Create a `project` folder
2. [Download vs_BuildTools.exe](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16) to `project`
3. Create a Dockerfile using the .NET Framework SDK 4.8 image

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 as build
   SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
   RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass; \
       iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')); \
       choco install sonarscanner-msbuild-net46 -y; \
       choco install jdk8 -y; \
       choco install powershell-core -y;

   # Install Crystal Reports for Visual Studio
   WORKDIR /installers
   # hack in oledlg dll so that Crystal Runtime will install. See
   # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072716/19977 for more info
   COPY Resources/Files/64/oledlg.dll /windows/syswow64/oledlg.dll
   COPY Resources/Files/32/oledlg.dll /windows/system32/oledlg.dll
   ARG CR_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000001263562020
   ARG CR_HASH=8665A5192240163177B0FDC7EA87C94A17F0476EFFF593FD90CB65361FC00A63
   SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
   RUN Invoke-WebRequest "$env:CR_DOWNLOAD_URL" -OutFile 'cr.msi'; \
       if ((Get-FileHash 'cr.msi').Hash -ne "$env:CR_HASH") { \
           Write-Error 'Crystal Reports hashes do not match. Stopping build.' \
       } \
       Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -Wait -ArgumentList '/i "C:\installers\cr.msi" /quiet /qn /norestart /L*V "C:\Windows\Temp\cr_install.log"'; \
       Remove-Item 'cr.msi'

   FROM build as dev
   WORKDIR /dev
   ```
4. Build my image

   ```
   docker build -t my-project . --target dev
   ```
5. Run my container

   ```
   docker run -it --rm -v "${pwd}:C:\dev" --name my-project my-project
   ```

   Mounting the volume to the current local directory gives me access to the vs_BuildTools.exe downloaded earlier.
6. Install the optional F# components. I tried several different options

   1. Install ManagedDesktopBuildTools with optional components

      ```
      start /w vs_BuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait --includeOptional
      ```

      ```
      start /w vs_BuildTools modify --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait --includeOptional
      ```
   2. Install F# Component Explicitly

      ```
      start /w vs_BuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.MSBuild --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait
      ```

      ```
      start /w vs_BuildTools modify --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.MSBuild --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait
      ```

In all cases I get a variety of including...

```
[08f8:0001][2021-05-10T20:49:21] Visual Studio Installer Version: 2.9.3365
[08f8:0001][2021-05-10T20:49:21] Raw Command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\setup.exe"  modify --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --quiet --norestart --nocache --includeOptional --locale en-US --activityId "d43641b0-241b-48be-b6ff-6625487b134e"
[08f8:0001][2021-05-10T20:49:21] Warning: Closing the installer with exit code 87
... more logs ...
[08f8:0001][2021-05-10T20:49:22] Warning: Failed to parse the command line arguments: The current operation needs either --channelId and
--productId or --installPath Usage: setup.exe modify [options]
... more logs ...
[08f8:0001][2021-05-10T20:49:22] Warning: Shutting down the application with exit code 87
[08f8:0001][2021-05-10T20:49:22] Closing the installer with exit code 87
[08f8:0001][2021-05-10T20:49:22] Exit Code: 87
```

Or

```
[07b8:0012][2021-05-10T22:33:50] Warning: Shutting down the application with exit code 1
[07b8:0012][2021-05-10T22:33:50] Warning: Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 (2) is already installed.
[07b8:0001][2021-05-10T22:33:50] Releasing singleton lock.
[07b8:0001][2021-05-10T22:33:50] Releasing singleton lock succeed.
[07b8:0001][2021-05-10T22:33:50] Releasing singleton lock.
[07b8:0001][2021-05-10T22:33:50] Singleton lock does not exist. Releasing singleton lock skipped.
[07b8:0001][2021-05-10T22:33:50] Closing the installer with exit code 1
```

Or even

```
[044c:0001][2021-05-10T22:55:26] Exception occured while trying to write telemetry session to the network. One or more errors occurred.
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Services.Telemetry.FlushTelemetrySession(Boolean shouldRecreate)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of the VS Build Tools are you using to install?  It looks like the latest (16.9)?  That only contains F# 5, right?

Comment: Perhaps that is part of the issue. I have been using the VS Build Tools 2019. The same version as in the .NET Framework 4.8 SDK docker image. I perhaps incorrectly assume that the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.MSBuild` refers to F# 4.x. I cannot seem to find a matrix of F# language version, runtime versions, and compiler versions to verify I am using the correct one.

Comment: According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5, F# 5 was introduced with VS 16.8. And according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019&preserve-view=true, there is no way to specify a version of the F# component. You just get one: F# 5.

Comment: But this raises a question of why you need F# 4.5. According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5, F# 5 will work with .NET Framework as long as you're targeting 4.7.2 or higher.  It looks like you're targeting 4.8.  So what's the issue exactly?

Comment: I have a series of F# scripts (.fsx) that automate the creation of PDF reports using Oracle and Crystal Reports. I called the .fsx scripts with fsi.exe. Oracle has .NET Framework and Core versions of the assemblies available. Crystal Reports only supports .NET Framework. I was under the assumption that F# 5 only ran on Core/.NET 5 but if I can target .NET Framework and load .NET Framework assemblies F#5 will work just fine. 1/2

Comment: However, when I ran dotnet fsi my-script.fsx I receive an `error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine' in any of C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4 C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\../../../packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0 C:\dev\. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\FSharp\` error. This made me think F# was running under .NET Core.  If I can target F# 5 and .NET Framework 4.8 and have everything 'just work' that'd be peachy! 2/2

Comment: How are you restoring packages?  Have you verified the container has the CrystalReports package during the build?

Comment: The Crystal Reports runtime is installed in the base image. I have updated the question with the full Dockerfile. We use this setup for other .NET Framework projects references Crystal Reports, so we know it works.

Comment: How is the project file referencing CrystalReports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TLDR

I was able to solve the issue by installing the [F# Compiler Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Compiler.Tools/10.2.3) using [paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/get-started.html). The F# Compiler Tools for F# 4.5 runs on .NET Framework (or or mono) unlike F# 5 which runs on .NET Core (or .NET 5).

## DETAILS

#### Create the Dockerfile

My Dockerfile doesn't look too much different from before. I still base it on the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK 4.8 image as I want access to the .NET SDK.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 as build
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

#
# INSTALL SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS DEVELOPER VERSION FOR MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO STUDIO 32 BIT & 64 BIT
# Downloads for CR can be found at https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html
#
WORKDIR /installers

# Add oledlg dlls so that the Crystal Reports runtime will install. For more infomation see:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072716/19977
COPY Resources/Files/64/oledlg.dll /windows/syswow64/oledlg.dll
COPY Resources/Files/32/oledlg.dll /windows/system32/oledlg.dll

ARG CR_DOWNLOAD_URL_32=https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000195592021
ARG CR_32_HASH=425D88E82832784A9E53897C43F54A6E0423FFCBFA536C12253378E5C4646CD7
ARG CR_DOWNLOAD_URL_64=https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000195602021
ARG CR_64_HASH=2BAB57DC3E8C69A2DB3835FEFF11E52B5D9C19020DC9A08302A97618F8304C1B

RUN Invoke-WebRequest "$env:CR_DOWNLOAD_URL_32" -OutFile 'cr32.msi'; \
    Invoke-WebRequest "$env:CR_DOWNLOAD_URL_64" -OutFile 'cr64.msi'; \
    if ((Get-FileHash 'cr32.msi').Hash -ne "$env:CR_32_HASH") { \
        Write-Error 'Crystal Reports 32 bit hashes do not match. Stopping build.' \
    } \
    if ((Get-FileHash 'cr64.msi').Hash -ne "$env:CR_64_HASH") { \
        Write-Error 'Crystal Reports 64 bit hashes do not match. Stopping build.' \
    } \
    Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -Wait -ArgumentList '/i "C:\installers\cr32.msi" /quiet /qn /norestart /L*V "C:\Windows\Temp\cr32_install.log"'; \
    Start-Process 'msiexec.exe' -Wait -ArgumentList '/i "C:\installers\cr64.msi" /quiet /qn /norestart /L*V "C:\Windows\Temp\cr64_install.log"'; \
    Remove-Item 'cr32.msi'; \
    Remove-Item 'cr64.msi';

FROM build as dev
WORKDIR /dev
```

#### Build the Image

While the Dockerfile settled we build the image.

```
docker build -t fsharp-image . --target dev
```

#### Run the Container

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd):C:\dev" --name fsharp-image fsharp-image
```

#### Install Paket

I followed the [Get Started](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/get-started.html) Paket instructions using the preferred (.NET Core) option. The commands were executed within the running container.

1. Install and restore paket

   ```
   dotnet new tool-manifest
   dotnet tool install paket
   dotnet tool restore
   ```
2. Create a paket dependencies file

   ```
   dotnet paket init
   ```

#### Install F# Compiler Tools

With Paket now installed we can install the F# Compiler Tools.

```
paket add FSharp.Compiler.Tools --version 10.2.3
```

#### Confirm F# 4.5 Installation

To confirm the F# 4.5 installation we run the following.

```
packages\FSharp.Compiler.Tools\tools\fsi.exe
```

This should be the output

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.2.3 for F# 4.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;
```

#### Run TestOpenCrystalReportsDocument.fsx

I then created a small script to test the complete installation.

```ml
// TestOpenCrystalReportsDocument.fsx
#r "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine"
#r "CrystalDecisions.Shared"

open CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
open CrystalDecisions.Shared

let openDoc path =
    let doc = new ReportDocument()
    doc.Load path
    doc

printfn "OPEN DOC"
let doc = openDoc "C:\\dev\\test.rpt"
printfn "SUCCESS"
```

Finally we run the script

```
packages\FSharp.Compiler.Tools\tools\fsi.exe TestOpenCrystalReportsDocument.fsx
```

The output shows we have no errors!

```
OPEN DOC
SUCCESS
```

#### Wrapping Up

To wrap up I commit the following files.

- Dockerfile
- paket.dependencies
- paket.lock
- .config/dotnet-tools.json

Whenever I re-run the container I only need to execute `dotnet tool restore` and `dotnet paket restore` to reinstall paket and the F# 4.5 Compiler tools.