# The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods' threw an exception

Tags: c#, docker, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently working with OpenCVSharp4 for fixing rotated/distorted image.

```
    public static void FixImagePerspective(string fullPath, PointF[] pointsArray)
    {
        Bitmap srcImg = Image.FromFile(fullPath) as Bitmap;

        var width = srcImg.Width;
        var height = srcImg.Height;

        Mat src = Cv2.ImRead(fullPath);
        var dst = new Mat();

        var dsize = new OpenCvSharp.Size(width, height);
        var srcTri = new Mat(4, 1, MatType.CV_32FC2, pointsArray);
        var dstTri = new Mat(4, 1, MatType.CV_32FC2, new int[] { 0, 0, height, 0, height, width, 0, width });

        var M = Cv2.GetPerspectiveTransform(srcTri, dstTri);

        Cv2.WarpPerspective(src, dst, M, dsize, InterpolationFlags.Linear, BorderTypes.Constant, new Scalar());

        Cv2.ImWrite($"C:\\tmp\\Fixed\\{name}_{count}_corrected.jpg", dst);
    }
```

This function worked properly from my local machine. But when deployed it into `windowsservercore-ltsc2019` Docker container. When ever it come to `Cv2.ImRead`, it throw the exception that

```
The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods' threw an exception
```

I've tried to use dependencies-walker to find the missing *.dll file inside the container and copy it accordingly, but it won't solve the issue.
I've also tried to install `vc_redist` on the docker container but it also didn't solve the issue.

Seem like there is an issue with running `OpenCVSharp4` inside docker container. I've already installed `OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win` packages. But it won't work

I'm using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` for my docker container.

Any tips on how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is probably some Windows API components that are not present in server core.

As a quick fix you can use the full windows API container `mcr.microsoft.com/windows` (now replaced by `mcr.microsoft.com/server`)

Windows container/host compatibility is tricky but I think `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809` is the equivalent full-API equivalent to your `ltsc2019`.

Once you have it running you may be able to [copy dlls from the full-api container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55821150/909199) to the servercore container using multiple layers in the dockerfile.

There's an [open github issue](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/589#issuecomment-475300250) about a dependency on the Windows Media Framework (not present on Windows Server by default) with a handy list of the dll files that can be copied to resolve the problem...